# Grafana Code Debugging

Tags: go, grafana, delve

I am newbie to Grafana, I have installed Grafana and did all the instructions given in the read me file. I'm using **Visual Code** for go lang now I just want to debug the Grafana code so that I can understand the process.

Can any one suggest me what I have to do. I have heard of debugger called Delve. Can any one tell me how to use it because when I use Delve it says that there is no build-able source files in the location.

I Have followed following Links :
        https://github.com/grafana/grafana , https://github.com/derekparker/delve

Comment: Formatted and corrected typo

Answer (score 4):

The grafana-server main.go file is not located in the root directory. Try `cd pkg/cmd/grafana-server` and start from there.